# How to return Future<String> in flutter and pass the value to Map<String>

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am successfully returning a Future to a String but then I cannot seem to find the right wat to assign and use the returned value.

Here I am getting the `String name`:

```
initState() {
    name();
    super.initState();
}
void name() async {
    String? name = await getName();
    print(name.toString());
}
```

From a `<Future String>`:

```
static Future<String?> getName() async {
    return "This is my name";
}
```

Then I need to pass the `name` to a `Map<String>`:

```
Map<String, String> NamesAll() {
    Map<String, String> result = new Map();
    FirstName = name;    //I get an error here: Undefined name 'name'.
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that I get an error in Map: `Undefined name 'name'`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's unclear what specifically you're trying to do. Are you trying to access the `name` variable? You can't access a variable declared in a function, so move it out of the function and make it a class field. Are you trying to call the `name` function? You need to add parentheses to call a function, e.g. `FirstName = name();` Beyond those possibilities, it's very hard to say what you need to do because with the given code it's very hard to say what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your code is somehow similar to this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String FirstName = '';

  @override 
  initState() {
    name();
    super.initState();
  }

  void name() async {
    // 1.
    String? name = await getName();
    print(name.toString());
  }

  Map<String, String> NamesAll() {
    Map<String, String> result = new Map();

    FirstName = name;
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If this is the case, then the `name` you defined inside the method name() can not be reached outside that method. For more info refer to [Lexical scopes](https://dart.dev/language/functions#lexical-scope).

If you wanted this to work, a possible solution would be:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String name = '';
  String FirstName = '';

  @override 
  initState() {
    name();
    super.initState();
  }

  void name() async {
    name = await getName();
    print(name.toString());
  }

  Map<String, String> NamesAll() {
    Map<String, String> result = new Map();

    FirstName = name;
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Where `name` is now global to the state class, therefore it is a mutable data now and can be reached by any method/member inside the `_MyHomePageState` class.

Edit 2:

In case you want to save the data to map:

```
Map<String, String> result = new Map();
String nameToAwait = await name();
result['keyName'] = nameToAwait; 
// you could also do
result['keyName'] = await name();
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks man. I cannot be so dumb :)

Comment: No worries. Please watch out how you name things in Dart too, as Dart prefers camelCase instead of PascalCase :).

Comment: Right now the `name` in `Map<String, String>` is blank because it's value is assigned before `name()` gets its value. How can I wait for `name()` value to be returned before passing it to `Map`?

Comment: Check edit 2 @BradG

Comment: if I do, `result['keyName'] = await name();`, then I have to change `Map` to `Future<Map>`. Consequently, when I call `NamesAll()` in the build widget, I get this error: `The argument type 'Future<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, String>?'`

Comment: Not really. I think you're missing some detail regarding your code. Awaiting for a value means Dart is not expecting a feature when assigning it to result['keyName']. Just tested on DartPad, my solution still works :).